# MySQL: Select Data from multiple Columns on Multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, select

I have following tables:

```
Sender
---------
ID, name, type, mobile


Receiver
-----------
ID, name, type, mobile


Ports
-----------
ID, name, city, country


Shipment
-----------
ID, Sender_ID, Receiver_ID, From_Port_ID, To_Port_ID, Date, Status
```

I was trying to display shipment table contents in my webpage with names instead of IDs. I can fetch sender and receiver name by the following query:

```
SELECT sender.name AS Sender, receiver.name AS Receiver, shipment.id 
FROM sender,receiver,shipment
WHERE shipment.sender_ID=sender.ID AND shipment.receiver_ID=receiver.ID
```

How to fetch port names from ports table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT sender.name as Sender, receiver.name as Receiver, ports_a.name as FromPort,
ports_b.name as ToPort

FROM Shipment as shipment

JOIN Sender
ON sender.ID= shipment.sender_ID

JOIN  Receiver  as receiver
ON receiver.ID= shipment.receiver_ID

JOIN Ports as ports_a
on ports_a.ID= shipment.From_Port_ID 

JOIN Ports as ports_b
on ports_b.ID= shipment.To_Port_ID
```

First line includes `SELECT`, as what you did, just put all the info you want to fetch.

The second part is, to specify from where you want to get the info. 
`FROM` will be the from table, which is the main table that connects all other tables.

Then that table, will be joined with other tables using the keyword `JOIN`. It's like connection table by having a common reference. This reference is the `ID` in `Shipment` table such as `sender_ID`.

For example `sender_ID` for will be matched with `Sender.id` from Sender table as in `Sender.id` #5 will be connected with `Shipment.sender_ID` #5.

Comment: Perfect, you guys are all awesome

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT sender.name as Sender, receiver.name as Receiver, shipment.id, ports.name AS Port 
FROM sender,receiver,shipment,ports 
WHERE shipment.sender_ID=sender.ID AND shipment.receiver_ID=receiver.ID AND ports.ID = shipment.From_Port_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it joining twice with `ports`:

```
select sender.name as Sender, receiver.name as Receiver, 
      shipment.id, port1.name as OriginPort, port2.name as DestinationPort
from sender,receiver,shipment, ports port1, ports port2 
WHERE shipment.sender_ID=sender.ID 
      AND shipment.receiver_ID=receiver.ID
      AND shipment.From_Port_ID = port1.id
      AND shipment.To_Port_ID = port2.id
```

I also suggest you to change your query to use the explicit syntax for join (see [Explicit vs implicit SQL joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/) for more information on this), as follows:

```
select sender.name as Sender, receiver.name as Receiver, 
      shipment.id, port1.name as OriginPort, port2.name as DestinationPort
from sender JOIN shipment ON sender.ID = shipment.sender_ID
        JOIN receiver ON shipment.receiver_ID=receiver.ID
        JOIN ports port1 ON shipment.From_Port_ID = port1.id
        JOIN ports port2 ON shipment.To_Port_ID = port2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I HOPE IS THAT WHAT YOU WANT !!!!...

```
select 
 S.name as Sender
,R.name as Receiver
,SH.id
,PFROM.name
,PTO.name

from shipment AS SH

INNER JOIN PORTS AS PFROM ON PFROM.ID = SH.From_Port_ID
INNER JOIN PORTS AS PTO ON PTO.ID = SH.From_Port_ID
INNER JOIN SENDER AS S ON SH.sender_ID=S.ID 
INNER JOIN RECEIVER AS R ON SH.receiver_ID=R.ID
```